# Gigabyte b650 DS3H secure boot won't boot from USB

Tags: bios, windows-11, secure-boot

Gigabyte b650 DS3H secure boot won't boot from USB.

I'm trying to run clean install for win 11 from USB drive system running on gigabyte b650 DS3H. I've made sure that TMP 2.0 is enabled and CSM is disabled. However bios can't see the plugged usb drive for booting. IO settings show that system recognizes the drive.

However when I reboot and select boot device it is not listed.

I tried to enable CSM which allow to boot from the drive (but not install windows ofc since secure boot is required.)

Random internet guide said to delete factory key and import one from media, but this does not work as system says that there is no eligible media for this.

Any help/links to sources would be appreciated.

Edit: I found comment from the customer: 'worked on BIOS-marked USB port' Maybe this is something important...

Comment: How did you create the installation media?  Which software did you use?

Comment: @Ramhound Bought it from retailer. (official MS media, along with rest of the components.)

Comment: You need to use a boot media that was created for Secure Boot. Which version of Windows is currently installed and is it functional?

Comment: You will want to create your own installation media using either Rufus or the Media Creation Tool. The installation media you have cannot be used based on your description

Comment: "However bios can't see the plugged usb drive for booting." Two likely possibilities: 1. Invalid *boot* partition. 2. Wrong USB format. For example, most BIOS cannot read exFAT.

Comment: @harrymc None. Clean drive.

Comment: Thankyou @ Ramhound and @ DrMoishe Pippik I'll try these.

Comment: @Ramhound Creation of new boot media worked. Create an answer and I'll accept this. (For future people facing this problem) Usb media in bought box had something wrong with it for some reason.